# Downloading a file from MySQL using Java EE and primefaces

Tags: java, mysql, file, io, javabeans

Well I have a database with a table that contains a BLOB field, the thing is that I need to make a link to download the files.

So far in my backing beans I have a method to generate each record with its respective file, and a method that reads the array of data.

When I use the P:Datatable to show the records I can view every single record, name and file accesing the file.methods in each one.

But I cannot find a way to make it downloadable, I has been searching the forum and the network for away to make something like this

(listadoArticulos.listado is the array of articles, each article contains a few String fields and a single blob)

I need to link to the file itself so the user can download it.

In my backing beans I need to make a method  so I can link it, the method has to pass the "File" in the database to bytes (I guess)

I will apreciate any help or direction

Answer (score 0):

You don't use JSF to generate the file download. The file download is done directly by a Java handler/servlet, which will set the content-type directly and stream the file content as bytes.

Comment: Yes, I am having the "problem" because I cannot find a way to do that in my baking beans

Comment: Which means you're aware that the issue is with your "backing beans" and not "jsf" or "primefaces" (tags you added), or the JSF file you gave? So why post those and not something regarding the backing beans, which is where you have to solve your problem?